# How to set PATH environment variable in CMake script?

Tags: cmake

I want to build my sources by Mingw compiler which in not placed on my system PATH.
I tried this in the beginning of my script:

```
set(Env{PATH} "c:/MyProject/Tools/mingw/bin/" "c:/MyProject/Tools/mingw/msys/1.0/bin/")
```

And this:

```
set(CMAKE_PROGRAM_PATH "c:/MyProject/Tools/mingw/bin/"   "c:/MyProject/Tools/mingw/msys/1.0/bin/")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH "c:/MyProject/Tools/mingw/bin/" "c:/MyProject/Tools/mingw/msys/1.0/bin/")
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROGRAM_PATH "c:/MyProject/Tools/mingw/bin/" "c:/MyProject/Tools/mingw/msys/1.0/bin/")
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH "c:/MyProject/Tools/mingw/bin/" "c:/MyProject/Tools/mingw/msys/1.0/bin/")
```

The first variant doesn't work at all. A suggest that I can't overwrite the value of the environment variable in CMake script.
The second script finds my mingw compiler, but catches the error while running gcc (can't find libgmp-10.dll which needs by gcc). This is because the PATH variable is not set to my Mingw.

Comment: Prepending to `ENV{PATH}` in a [toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.25/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) Works For Me™ on Windows with CMake 3.25.2: `set(ENV{PATH} "/path/to/mingw;$ENV{PATH}")`, at least during the initial configuration/generation phase.  Compilers fail to run with the subsequent Ninja invocation though :(

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Write a script file to start CMake.

On Windows make a batch file:

```
@echo off
set path=c:\MyProject\Tools\mingw\bin;c:\MyProject\Tools\mingw\msys\1.0\bin
"C:\Program Files\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake-gui.exe"
```

On Linux make a bash script:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/your/path
```

Comment: you can use setlocal in a script to automatically undo the change to the path when the batch file exits (if desired). There are also environment variables `ProgramFiles(x86)` and `ProgramFiles` that should be used instead of hard coding `C:\Program Files`

Answer (score 22):

CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROGRAM_PATH is not meant to be modified, use

```
LIST(APPEND CMAKE_PROGRAM_PATH  "c:/MyProject/Tools/mingw/bin/" ...)
```

Comment: Looks like this doesn't manipulate the `PATH` environement variable! If you call custom commands with programs that depend on DLL files located in the given path, the DLL files are not found.

Answer (score 4):

You might approach it as if it were a cross compiling toolchain, even if you're not cross compiling from Linux to Windows as in this example:

http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CmakeMingw

After you follow that guide you set the mingw toolchain at the command line when calling cmake:

```
~/src/helloworld/ $ mkdir build
~/src/helloworld/ $ cd build
~/src/helloworld/build/ $ cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/Toolchain-mingw32.cmake
```

then if you're using this a whole lot you can make an alias to limit typing in that ugly -D every time you want to regenerate makefiles:

```
alias mingw-cmake='cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/Toolchain-mingw32.cmake'
```

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the question. The toolchain file will only work if the bin folder from mingw is already on the system path.