# How to set runtime PATH for CMake custom command on Windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio, dll, path, cmake

I'm trying to port a *nix, CMake-based project to Windows. One header file needed by the main library is generated by a custom program, so the `CMakeLists.txt` file contains something like this:

```perl
add_executable(TableGenerator "TableGenerator.cpp")
target_link_libraries(TableGenerator ${LibFoo_LIBRARY})

add_custom_command(OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Table.h"
                   COMMAND TableGenerator "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Table.h"
                   DEPENDS TableGenerator)
```

An important detail is that `TableGenerator` uses the external shared library `LibFoo`. For example under Linux, everything works fine, because `libfoo.so` is installed in one of the system library directories like `/usr/local/lib`, or CMake even sets the rpath attribute in the executable, saying where exactly to find the library.

On Windows, however, these kind of libraries are usually not installed into the system but are rather just extracted or compiled into some arbitrary directory in or near the build tree. In order for `TableGenerator` to run, the `foo.dll` would need to be available in or copied to one of the [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx) paths (say `%WINDIR%\System32` or the build output directory for `TableGenerator`), which is not desirable.

How can I set the `PATH` environment variable for the custom command, i.e. to be used not [during the CMake run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584602/how-to-set-path-environment-variable-in-cmake-script) but during the actual custom build step runtime?

Comment: Ordinarily you would put a copy of the DLL into the same directory as the executable.

Comment: Indeed, all this was just about how to avoid doing that. A practical reason, for example, is if the DLL has more DLL dependencies whose names would need to be all hardcoded in the child project.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

While still doing my research in order to ask the question properly, I have found three solutions. Considering how hard it was to find this information, I decided to post the question and answer here anyway.

---

### 1. Using global variable `CMAKE_MSVCIDE_RUN_PATH`

There is a special variable dedicated to solving this exact problem – [CMAKE_MSVCIDE_RUN_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/variable/CMAKE_MSVCIDE_RUN_PATH.html). If set, it results in a line like this being added to the custom build step script:

```
set PATH=<CMAKE_MSVCIDE_RUN_PATH>;%PATH%
```

So all that's needed then is something like this at a good place:

```perl
set(CMAKE_MSVCIDE_RUN_PATH ${LibFoo_RUNTIME_LIBRARY_DIRS})
```

I have originally noticed this variable only in CMake sources, because it used to be undocumented until CMake 3.10. So you might not be able to find it in documentation for older versions of CMake, but don't worry, it's been [supported since 2006](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/commit/0005d625a0f46e6071adfb394b82e5bf8c74a291).

**Advantages:**
▪ Can be enabled at one central place
▪ No change at all in any of the `add_custom_command()` commands elsewhere is needed
▪ Only the path itself is set, no batch commands need to be written explicitly
▪ The obvious choice with clear name and intent

**Disadvantages:**
▪ Global for the whole CMake project and all custom commands
▪ Works with the "Visual Studio 9 2008" and above generators only

---

### 2. Setting the PATH explicitly using two `COMMAND` parameters

The script being generated for the custom build step in Visual Studio contains some prologue, then the commands themselves and then some epilogue. Wouldn't it be possible to simply add `set PATH=...` before the real command through another `COMMAND` parameter?

The [documentation for `add_custom_command()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/add_custom_command.html?) says:

> `COMMAND`
>   Specify the command-line(s) to execute at build time. If more than one `COMMAND` is specified they will be executed in order, but *not* necessarily composed into a stateful shell or batch script.

So no, that's not guaranteed to be possible. But the Visual Studio project generator actually [does it like this](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/a11dda1c4883eddf763ba1eb2979b45220886b01/Source/cmLocalVisualStudioGenerator.cxx#L193), i.e. the individual commands are just appended one after another, so the following does the job:

```perl
add_custom_command(OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Table.h"
                   COMMAND set "PATH=${LibFoo_RUNTIME_LIBRARY_DIRS};%PATH%"
                   COMMAND TableGenerator "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Table.h"
                   DEPENDS TableGenerator)
```

**Advantages:**
▪ The PATH can be changed for each custom command explicitly

**Disadvantages:**
▪ Relies on an undocumented behavior of the generator
▪ It's necessary to rewrite the whole command for Windows and keep both versions in sync
▪ Each custom command must be changed explicitly

---

### 3. Using `file(GENERATE ...)` to create a custom script

The [documentation for `add_custom_command()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/add_custom_command.html?) quoted above continues:

> To run a full script, use the `configure_file()` command or the `file(GENERATE)` command to create it, and then specify a `COMMAND` to launch it.

This is a bit messy because of the additional temporary files and commands:

```perl
file(GENERATE OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/RunTableGenerator.cmd"
              CONTENT "set PATH=${LibFoo_RUNTIME_LIBRARY_DIRS};%PATH%
                       %1 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Table.h")
add_custom_command(OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Table.h"
                   COMMAND "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/RunTableGenerator.cmd" "$<TARGET_FILE:TableGenerator>"
                   DEPENDS TableGenerator)
```

Notice the awkward way of sending the path to the executable as an argument. This is necessary because the script is writen once, but `TableGenerator` might be in different locations for different configurations (debug and release). If the generator expression was used directly in the content, a CMake error would be printed and the project would not build correctly for all but one configuration.

**Advantages:**
▪ The PATH can be changed for each custom command explicitly
▪ A fully documented and recommended solution

**Disadvantages:**
▪ Very noisy in the CMakefiles
▪ It's necessary to rewrite the whole command for Windows and keep both versions in sync
▪ Each custom command must be changed explicitly

---

### 4. Launch the custom command through CMake wrapper

See the other answer below contributed by Dvir Yitzchaki.

---

I had personally settled on the solution #1 because it was clean and simple, even before it got properly documented and supported by CMake in version 3.10. It should be the best way forward for you as well, unless you need to do something even more special.

Comment: Unfortunatly, I didn't manage to make it work on my setup.... had to copy dll's with a post build custom_target.

Where should the result of the CMAKE_MSVCIDE_RUN_PATH variable be seen ? I saw some lines appearing as CustomBuild in the vcxproj file... but unable to launch the debugger from VS and get the DLL loaded :/

Comment: I see. This question deals with CMake custom commands (e.g. you have `blah.template` in the project and it gets transformed through some preprocessor to `blah.h` as part of the compilation). You want to change DLL paths for running/debugging apps under VS, which is a different thing. You can avoid copying DLLs around by adding the path manually under "Project properties > Debugging > Environment" as e.g. `Path=$(SolutionDir)external\somelib\bin;%Path%`. Unfortunately automating that in CMake seems to be harder – see https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/8884 for more info.

Comment: Ok I wasn't sure about that, now it's clear. thanks !

Comment: Voting up as the custom command in section 2 helped my set PYTHONPATH in Linux. It is equivalent to `PYTHONPATH=<mypath> python script.py`.

Answer (score 11):

There is another way besides what Yirkha wrote and that is to run the executable through cmake and use cmake's -E option to set the environment.

So in your case it will be:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Table.h"
               COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env "PATH=${LibFoo_RUNTIME_LIBRARY_DIRS}" $<TARGET_FILE:TableGenerator> "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Table.h"
               DEPENDS TableGenerator)
```

See http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2006-March/008522.html for details.