# CTest, CMake & MinGW: Executables build, but fail to run, because fresh DLL is not found

Tags: dll, cmake, environment-variables, mingw, ctest

The top-level `CMakeLists.txt` contains:

```
include(CTest)
add_subdirectory(lib)
add_subdirectory(demo)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

`lib/CMakeLists.txt` is essentially:

```
add_library(MyLib <sources>)
```

`demo/CMakeLists.txt` is essentially:

```
add_executable(Demo demo.c)
target_link_libraries(Demo MyLib)
```

`test/CMakeLists.txt` is just:

```
add_test(NAME Demo COMMAND Demo)
```

From a gitlab-runner, we execute:

```
cmake -G "Ninja" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\opt\x64 -B. ..
cmake --build
ctest --output-on-failure
```

The first two steps succeed; the third one fails with:

```
Start 1: Demo
1/1 Test #1: Demo .......................Exit code 0xc0000135
***Exception:   0.03 sec
```

If I retry:

```
cmake --install
ctest
```

then the test succeeds. So the sole problem is that `build/lib/mylib.dll` is not found when running `ctest`. Whereas `C:\opt\x64\lib` is in `PATH`, and therefore the DLL is found after `cmake --install`. Which, however, is not what we want: `ctest` shall always use the fresh DLL from the current build, not the installed version.

Under Linux, everything works correctly. Why doesn't it for Windows and MinGW? Is this a bug in CMake? How can we work around this so that `ctest` executes correctly on all platforms?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy DLL files into the same folder as the executable using CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671916/how-to-copy-dll-files-into-the-same-folder-as-the-executable-using-cmake)

Comment: I edited my question to make clear that it is not only about a workaround but also about understanding _why_ clean standard CMake code does not work.

Comment: It does work correctly.  Your runtime environment is wrong and you need to fix it.  It's no different from having to set RPATH on Linux if you built a shared library that is already installed and you need to use the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue seems to be the Windows DLL search procedure failing to find `mylib.dll` when your `Demo` executable is run by `ctest`. The Windows DLL search order is specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-desktop-applications):

> 1. The directory from which the application loaded.
> 2. The system directory. Use the `GetSystemDirectory` function to get the path of this directory.
> 3. The 16-bit system directory. There is no function that obtains the path of this directory, but it is searched.
> 4. The Windows directory. Use the `GetWindowsDirectory` function to get the path of this directory.
> 5. The current directory.
> 6. The directories that are listed in the `PATH` environment variable. Note that this does not include the per-application path specified by
>      the `App Paths` registry key. The `App Paths` key is not used when
>      computing the DLL search path.

So, you could modify your `PATH` environment variable to *also* include the location of the fresh DLL from the current build.

A better, less error-prone solution might be to place the DLL in the same directory as the `Demo` executable. You can force CMake to use the same **binary** directory for both the DLL and executable by modifying your top-level CMake file:

```
include(CTest)
add_subdirectory(lib ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/demo)
add_subdirectory(demo ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/demo)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

Alternatively, as a less localized approach, you can place the DLL in the same directory as the executable by setting [`CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html):

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
```

Yet another alternative:

```
add_test(NAME Demo COMMAND Demo WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
```

Comment: I prefer using `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ` to put the `DLL` and `exe` into the same folder instead of forcing the binary folder location via `add_subdirectory()`.

Comment: @fdk1342 Yes, this is also a valid approach, although seems to be less localized, as I believe it would apply to all targets. You could set the target-specific property, however, using [`RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html#prop_tgt:RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY).

Comment: The library is our product; the demo programs and the tests are auxiliary. Therefore I would dislike to move the library from lib to demo. Is there an idiomatic way in CMake to tell the demo programs where to find the DLL?

Comment: If you don't mind, I'll edit your answer to add a third approach: call `add_test` with the `WORKING_DIRECTORY` pointing to lib.

Comment: @JoachimW Then, you could instead put the `demo` build artifacts in the `lib` folder by changing `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/demo` to `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib`. In general, you can either *modify* your runtime environment, by updating your `PATH` environment variable, updating it via [`ctest`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html#environment-variables), using one of work-arounds suggested in my answer, or those already documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39807774/3987854).

Comment: @JoachimW Yes, if it best solves your issue feel free to modify, or post your own answer!

Answer (score 5):

A more modern approach using generator expressions and appending to the test environment PATH:

```
add_test(NAME mytest ...)

set_tests_properties(mytest PROPERTIES ENVIRONMENT_MODIFICATION
                     "PATH=path_list_prepend:$<$<BOOL:${WIN32}>:$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:my_library>>")
```

This will append the directory containing "my_library" to the PATH used by the test runner when building on Windows, otherwise there will be no change.  No need to copy libraries or mess around with the locations of build products, or to alter PATH directly or use a specific working directory.

Comment: This is a good answer, but on CMake 3.27+ one has access to `TARGET_RUNTIME_DLL_DIRS`, which does the same job even better, as I explain in my answer. Still +1.

Answer (score 1):

@alex-reinking's answer is an awesome approach, but it fails when multiple folders are used because the list is not escaped. This one works though:

```
"PATH=path_list_prepend:$<JOIN:$<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLL_DIRS:Demo>,\;>"
```

It takes into account that this expansion is only used on windows where `;` is the path separator.

Answer (score 0):

An *even more* modern (CMake 3.27+) approach than the one in Roger's answer is to use [`TARGET_RUNTIME_DLL_DIRS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:TARGET_RUNTIME_DLL_DIRS).

```
add_test(NAME Demo COMMAND Demo)

set_tests_properties(
    Demo
    PROPERTIES
    ENVIRONMENT_MODIFICATION
        "PATH=path_list_prepend:$<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLL_DIRS:Demo>"
)
```

This has one major advantage: it doesn't require updates when the dependencies of `Demo` change!